# How to use different database within same app in django?

Tags: python, django, database

I have a app named xyz and I have 2 views in that app view1.py and view2.py 
I have router configured as

```
if model._meta.app_label == 'xyz'
    return database1
```

Is there a way to select a different database from this app 'xyz'.

I mean two different database within same app.

Is there a way or does django allow this in first place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The configuration of database related stuff is mostly done in settings.py file. So to add multiple database to our django project we need add them in DATABASES dictionary.

These settings go in **`Settings.py`**

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['path.to.DemoRouter']
DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING = {'user_data': 'users_db',
                        'customer_data':'customers_db'}

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'users_db': {
        'NAME': 'user_data',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'USER': 'postgres_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'password'
    },
    'customers_db': {
        'NAME': 'customer_data',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'mysql_cust',
        'PASSWORD': 'root'
    }
}
```

With multiple databases it will be good to talk about Database Router. The default routing scheme ensures that if a database isn’t specified, all queries fall back to the default database. Database Router defaults to [].

Put this in `models.py`

```
class DemoRouter:
    """
    A router to control all database operations on models in the
    user application.
    """
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to read user models go to users_db.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label == 'user_data':
            return 'users_db'
        elif model._meta.app_label == 'customer_data':
            return 'customer_db'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to write user models go to users_db.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label == 'user_data':
            return 'users_db'
        elif model._meta.app_label == 'customer_data':
            return 'customer_db'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """
        Allow relations if a model in the user app is involved.
        """
        if obj1._meta.app_label == 'user_data' or \
           obj2._meta.app_label == 'user_data':
           return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        """
        Make sure the auth app only appears in the 'users_db'
        database.
        """
        if app_label == 'user_data':
            return db == 'users_db'
        return None
```

Respective models would be modified as

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.Charfield(ax_length=100)
    . . .
        class Meta:
        app_label = 'user_data'

class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    . . .
        class Meta:
        app_label = 'customer_data'
```

Few helpful commands while working with multiple databases.

```
 $ ./manage.py migrate --database=users_db
```

Comment: Does DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING even need to be used?

Comment: Where is the makemigrations?